# how to get the pixel values of a region in a grayscale image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I would like to get the pixel values of the region marked as red rectangle.I want to crop the image after that

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will solve your problem. But there can be several better solutions. Next time please don't just ask the question, instead show what you've tried.

```
% 20151116
% crop image by area

clc; clear all;

img = imread('xgOFu.png');
subplot(1,5,1);
imshow(img);
xl1 = xlim;
title('Original');

imgr = img(:,:,1);
subplot(1,5,2);
imshow(imgr);
xlim(xl1);
title('Red channel');

imgb = im2bw(imgr,.9);
subplot(1,5,3);
imshow(imgb);
xlim(xl1);
title('Binary');

s  = regionprops(imgb);

c1 = s.BoundingBox(1);
c2 = s.BoundingBox(1)+s.BoundingBox(3)-1;
r1 = s.BoundingBox(2);
r2 = s.BoundingBox(2)+s.BoundingBox(4)-1;

subplot(1,5,4);
imgc = imgb(r1:r2,c1:c2,:);
imshow(imgc);
xlim(xl1);
title('Crop with border');

s2  = regionprops(imcomplement(imgc));

c3 = s2.BoundingBox(1)+c1;
c4 = s2.BoundingBox(1)+s2.BoundingBox(3)-1+c1;
r3 = s2.BoundingBox(2)+r1;
r4 = s2.BoundingBox(2)+s2.BoundingBox(4)-1+r1;

imgc2 = img(r3:r4,c3:c4,:);
subplot(1,5,5);
imshow(imgc2);
xlim(xl1);
title('Crop without border');
```

Output:

[image]

Updated answer for older version without `regionprops`.

```
% 20151116
% filter image by area 2

clc; clear all;

img = imread('xgOFu.png');
imgr = img(:,:,1);
imgb = im2bw(imgr,.9);

[r, c] = find(imgb(:,:,1)==1);
r1 = min(r);
r2 = max(r);
c1 = min(c);
c2 = max(c);
img2 = img(r1:r2,c1:c2,:);

img2r = img2(:,:,1);
img2b = im2bw(img2r,.9);

[r, c] = find(img2b(:,:)==0);
r1 = min(r);
r2 = max(r);
c1 = min(c);
c2 = max(c);
img3 = img2(r1:r2,c1:c2,:);
imshow(img3);
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand your comment. Which version of Matlab you use?

Comment: Seems regionprops is not available in your Matlab version. I will try to update the solution. You too keep trying.

Comment: @Huádéní華得尼 `regionprops` has been available since before R2006a.  "Older" versions of MATLAB isn't the problem.  I've used `regionprops` since R2008.

Comment: @rayryeng, That I really did not know. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can see when the function was introduced into MATLAB by visiting the documentation page for it and scrolling down to the bottom.

Comment: Can you try the second code and let us know the error.

Comment: Then, you did not get any result as well? Can you link us to a screen capture of your Matlab window after you run for each version.

Comment: @abcd you're getting that error because you are adding in code that wasn't originally there. That indexing into the bounding box property only returns ONE number yet you expect two. So it wasn't a problem with this code... It's how you are running it.